# why does Guava's Sets::hashCodeImpl have a weird loop update with double complement?

Tags: java, set, guava, hashcode

Guava computes the hash code of a set like this:

```
static int hashCodeImpl(Set<?> s) {
    int hashCode = 0;

    for(Iterator var2 = s.iterator(); var2.hasNext(); hashCode = ~(~hashCode)) {
        Object o = var2.next();
        hashCode += o != null ? o.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    return hashCode;
}
```

this is efficient and elegant - we use a commutative operation (addition) to "mix in" the hash codes of the objects, so that we get the same value regardless of order we iterate over the elements.

What I'm not sure about is the update condition in the for loop: `hashCode = ~(~hashCode)` seems to have no effect (IntelliJ's code inspector suggests to simplify the expression and then remove the self-assignment).

What's going on?

Comment: Intriguing. For what its worth, this is a pretty bad hashing impl: Hashing `null` to 0 is a bad idea (it means the hashcode of [a, b] and the hashcode of [a, b, null]).

Comment: @rzwitserloot That's quite literally [the recommended implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#hashCode()) though FYI: _the hash code of a set is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of the elements in the set, where the hash code of a null element is defined to be zero_. Interesting point of yours nonetheless.

Comment: @sp00m Yes, and that is a stupid definition, but remains due to two esoteric considerations: [A] conflicting definitions of what 'backwards compatible' truly means. Team OpenJDK has decided that changing hashCode isn't backwards compatible. They're not wrong, of course. Technically any change is backwards incompatible, really (see [Hyrum's Law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com)), and [B] j.u.Set tries to be equals/hashCode transparent relative to subtypes which effectively forces the javadoc to dictate precise impls of equals and hashCode.

Comment: But, @sp00m, thanks for pointing out the recommended implementation: That explains _why_ the guava hashcode impl is what it is, warts and all. I stick with my point that this is not 'efficient' nor 'elegant' (in OP's words), but guava's implementation is nevertheless correct.

Answer (score 3):

Although still a tad cryptic, [the latest source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java#L1758) explains it (introduced by [86aa9f0](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/86aa9f060deed8a128608e1b16e25a8e188aba7e)):

```
hashCode = ~~hashCode;
// Needed to deal with unusual integer overflow in GWT.
```

Comment: To highlight: In java, `~~foo` is a complete noop if `foo` is an `int`, as it is here. However, in GWT (and guava is specifically designed to work in GWT), your java code is transpiled to javascript, and that means alls ints silently turn into doubles, because javascript doesn't have ints. In javascript, on these secret doubles, `~~foo` is _not_ a no-op: It 'integerizes': It's `(int) foo`, but in javascript, with a hacky move. Presumably guava would do this regardless of cost (as it needs to work in GWT), but I bet the cost is really low, as hotspot probably eliminates double NEGs.

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot. If you'd turn this into an answer I'd accept it, or sp00m if you'd like to fold this into your answer I think it will make it more complete.

Comment: well, my question was motivated by some curiosity, and I feel your answer doesn't really quench that particular thirst (if anything, it makes it only more mysterious)